# Is there a way to implement play all function using the $scope.tracks in ion audio library?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ion-audio library to  play songs. The playlist works fine when clicking the play button (every song has its own play button).

My objective now is to play the list of songs automatically without trigging the play button.

Comment: Awesome. What have you tried to do to resolve your problem so far? Update your question with more details so people can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: 1. i have created a listener for the song that can track if the current song is finished.
2.when it finished the index of the $scope.tracks will increment for the next song to play, unfortunately the next song is not playing despite the index of the $scope.track increment already